# How to copy the entire sheet to newly created sheet referencing the sheet's name in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to create a sheet and rename it from referencing a cell in another sheet. This worked so far.

However, I'd like to copy and paste everything as values but maintaining the format from the old sheet to this newly created sheet. I don't know how to reference this just newly renamed sheet.

**Code as follows:**

```
Private Sub CreateSheet()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets("OldSheet"))

'the new sheet has the name from B3 of the old sheet.
ws.Name = Sheets("OldSheet").Range("B3")

'this copy paste part doesn't work, it gives an error.

Sheets("OldSheet").Copy
Sheets("ws").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't be easier just copy sheet (not creating new, empty one) and try it to paste into workbook, not worksheet?

Comment: Thanks guys, I am not advanced and have difficulty to understand your suggestions, but thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code to copy the data from one sheet to another. Found few issues with the code you were using.

- You have to make the new sheet visible.  (optional though).
- Select the range you want to copy from old to new sheet. (Below code will copy range `A1:C5` and paste it from `A1` range of new sheet.

```vb
Private Sub CreateSheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             Worksheets("OldSheet"))

    'the new sheet has the name from B3 of the old sheet.
    ws.Name = Sheets("OldSheet").Range("B3")
    ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible

    'this copy paste part doesn't work, it gives an error.

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OldSheet").Range("A1:C5").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Name).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Name).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

End Sub
```

**Update:**
As suggested in comments you can use `UsedRange` to copy.
You can replace below line of code in original code above.

```vb
uRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OldSheet").UsedRange.Address
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OldSheet").Range(uRange).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Name).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Name).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

Comment: Thank you very much! One question, can we not copy the entire sheet or do we have to specify the range of the copied sheet? However, I still need to maintain the format of the old sheet. Any input there? Thanks!

Comment: Sure you can. Please use `UsedRange.Value` as per the comments mentioned in the post.

Comment: You mean like this? ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OldSheet").Range(UsedRange.Value).Copy

Comment: It worked, but it only copied the values and forgot to carry the format over. Do I have to paste twice, one for values and another one for format?

Comment: please check my updated answer. In this case you don't have to mention the range as well.

Comment: For format copy you have to use `Paste:=xlPasteAll` instead of `Paste:=xlPasteValues`

Comment: PasteAll also copies formulas with it. I just want values and the formatted text without formulas. Any thoughts here?

Comment: Oh you don't want formulas. Then you have to `PasteSpecial` twice using `xlPasteValues` and then `xlPasteFormats`. Hope this will help

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way to do it. Create a copy of the existing sheet and then use `UsedRange.Value = UsedRange.Value`

```
With ThisWorkbook
    .Sheets("OldSheet").Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)

    With .Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        .Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OldSheet").Range("B3").Value
        .UsedRange.Value = .UsedRange.Value
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to maintain the copied formats as well? I tried using Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats. It doesn't work.

Comment: The method that I gave above will preserve the formats as well :)

Comment: Or maybe you replied under the wrong post? Maybe you wanted to ask that question to @stud3nt?

Comment: @purpleblau It is a better answer with lesser code :). Maybe mark this as an answer and take out mine.

Comment: You both were great of help! I prefer the first answer because I only understood that one. LOL.

Comment: @purpleblau: you are under no compulsion to choose an answer which you do not "like" :)

Comment: Yours is elegant, but I am just not that advanced to understand your code :)